# Tricky SQL Query (for me at least!)

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT  trackingno, COUNT(trackingno) AS NumberOfTimes 
FROM shippinginfo
GROUP BY trackingno HAVING (COUNT(trackingno)>1) 
ORDER BY NumberOfTimes DESC
```

It reports something along the lines of

```
Trackingno  |  NumberofTimes
12345       |  2
23456       |  2
34567       |  3
```

Is there a way to do the query so that I show other column data?

```
Trackingno  |  OrderId
12345       |  oid1
12345       |  oid2
23456       |  oid3
23456       |  oid4
34567       |  oid5
34567       |  oid6
```

Basically I am looking for any DUPLICATE tracking numbers (trackingno) in the table, then report the tracking number and the orderid (orderid) for the duplicate tracking number rows so that I can contact the customers that have duplicate tracking numbers.

Comment: So what is the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM shippinginfo
 WHERE trackingno IN (

    SELECT trackingno
      FROM shippinginfo
  GROUP BY trackingno
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

)
```

So in the inner query you're selecting all `trackingno` that are duplicated, then in outer you select whatever you need

Comment: Great!  One more addition, i just realized after running your query that we have a bunch of rows with blank trackingno (not null, just no data).  those are all being returned as they should be based on the query.  Is there a way to exclude the blank values?

Comment: Just add `WHERE trackingno != ''` or what you need in the inner?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Trackingno,orderId 
FROM shippinginfo
WHERE Trackingno IN (
                      SELECT trackingno
                      FROM shippinginfo
                      GROUP BY trackingno
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

                     )
```

Comment: seems to be working, is there a way for the tracking number to show as well?  i only see orderid data and the tracking no column is blank